# Using HstoreField in Django/ElasticSearch

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm new to elastic search and I really want to implement it in my Django project.
 My problem: I want to store a Python dict object

```
 ({'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2', [...]})
```

and be sure that my search will look each key.
In Django I use `Hstore` field and I can access my datas doing

```
Model.objects.get(hstorefield__key='value')
```

Does anyone has an idea to do it using elastic search and be sure that all my keys for my Hstorefield are tracked ?

Thanks for help !

Here is my Django model:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    code = models.BigIntegerField()
    url_off = models.URLField()
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_modified_t = models.DateTimeField()
    created_t = models.DateTimeField()
    metadatas = HStoreField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default any and all fields you index into elasticsearch in your documents will be indexed and available for search and filtering. All you have to do is produce a document that also contains the fields from you `HStoreField`. If you want to control your mappings for those fields you need to define them first, for example using a `DocType` (0) class (analogous to django's `Model`):

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Long, Text, Keyword,Date, Object, InnerDoc

class Metadata(InnerDoc):
    meta_field = Text()
    meta_number = Long()
    ...

class Product(DocType):
    code = Long()
    creator = Text(fields={'keyword': Keyword()})
    last_modified_t = Date()
    metadata = Object(Metadata)
    class Meta:
        index = 'i'

# create the index in elasticsearch, only run once
Product.init()
```

Then you just need to create a method on your model that will serialize it into the `Product` class:

```
def to_search(self):
    return Product(
      _id=self.pk,
      code=self.code,
      creator=self.creator,
      metadata=Metadata(**self.metadatas)
    )
```

Hope this helps!

0 - http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html#doctype

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot !!